# implementing slug in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration, slug

I have tried to do url_title().

but how to customize this function?

Comment: Seriously this is a terrible question. Give us a clue why don't you! Anyway despite your total lack of information about what or how you want to do something you could look at this CI library https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Slug-Library

Comment: yup....here i don't want to remove spacial characters i just want to relplace it with "dash".. but url title() is totaly remove all characters and only replace space with "dash". so i need to customize this url title();

Comment: You should have said that i your question

Answer (score 0):

**ok guys... i found the solution....
i customize the url title in url_helper..with use**

$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $str);

**and its work**